# Dependency Injection in .net 4.7?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

I'm a little confused as to what integrated options I have for DI. I see it's pretty straightforward for .net core (for my particular projects), but I don't need to build a cross platform app and don't see the advantage to using core. However, it doesn't look like .net framework applications are still setup with Global.asax and without Startup.cs so does that mean there is no integrated DI option for .net framework 4.7? Do I still need to get a 3rd party solution or is there a way to use the same DI workflow in a .net framework project as is used in a core project?

Comment: DI is a first class citizen only in dotnet core, your only option would be a framework such as Autofac or Ninject

Comment: @saj ok thanks. That's too bad :/

Comment: That is not true u can have a full .NET Framework ASP.NET Core Application until ASP.NET Core 2.2

Comment: You don't see the advantage of .NET Core? Even if you aren't interested in cross platform, there's still improved csproj and ability to work with IDEs besides VS, ability to ship the framework along with the app (enabling side by side deployments, better performance, more command line options, better container support etc. If you're starting new development, you absolutely should be using .NET Core instead of .NET Framework. .NET Core/Standard should be the default choice, and you should only use .NET Framework if you have a specific reason to do so.

Comment: @mason Lol, I understand why you interpreted my comment the way you did, but I absolutely did not mean it like that. Yes of course I totally get the benefits of .net core and I think it's really cool. What I really meant is that I don't believe there is any significant advantage to converting our existing projects to .net core that justify the work involved. Sorry for confusion. Don't hate me. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Dependency Injection is not integrated by default in classic asp.net, you need to add a nuget package to handle DI (only integrated by default in asp.net core and later versions).

Comment: yes something like autofac.

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT:** Even though I found out how to do it as explained below, I still ended up going with Autofac because I didn't realize the Microsoft's solution only supports constructor injection, but not property injection.

I found instructions on how to do it here. I know link answers are bad, but I don't have time to do any more than this. If someone else wants to make an answer with full instructions I will mark it.

https://scottdorman.blog/2016/03/17/integrating-asp-net-core-dependency-injection-in-mvc-4/

Also note that if you are not using Owin already, it is not required. You can set it up just the same in `Application_Start` method of `Global.asax`. Only change you would need to make is when it references the `Startup` class in a statement that reflectively gets all the Controller classes, you will need to change that to be the class the code is in (or any other class in your assembly).

Comment: Page not found :-(

Comment: @Mike sorry about that. Have you considered Autofac? In retrospect I would rather use it anyway... and it is very easy to get started with. I've used Ninject and Castle also and between the 3 I definitely prefer Autofac.

Comment: Thanks, will look into it.