# Integrating Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection in ASP.NET 4.6.1 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection, .net-framework-version

I have been using .NET Core 3.1 for most of my projects, but currently there is an existing project that uses .NET Framework 4.6.1

I am having difficulties to implement dependency injection to the .NET Framework 4.6.1, not sure where did I do wrong.

Here is what I understand and done so far:

- .NET Framework 4.6.1 runs Global.asax.cs -> Application_Start() upon run
- .NET Core 3.1 runs Startup.cs upon run

This is how the Dependency Injection was added in the .NET Core 3.1

Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        RegisterServices(services);

        ServiceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
    private void RegisterServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddOptions();
        services.AddTransient<IMemberServices, MemberService>();
    }
```

How do I add the dependency for IMemberServices with MemberService at .NET Framework 4.6.1

Global.asax.cs

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        //What to write here?
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use StructureMap or AutoFac or any other container.

Comment: Depedency injection is natively supported by Net 4.7.2 +. I highly recommend to update to this version at first

Comment: There are bugs with using core with any version of Net before 4.7.2.  Net 4.7.2 fixed all the bugs to make Core and Net compatible.

Comment: @Serge @ jdweng
After upgrading to .NET Framework 4.7.2 how to I do it?
I tried open a new project with .NET Framework 4.7.2 but I still can't do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dependency Injection in .net 4.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54584671/dependency-injection-in-net-4-7)

Comment: @cassandrad you can start with it https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/use-dependency-injection-in-webforms-application/

Comment: @cassandrad or this one https://www.infoworld.com/article/3397003/how-to-use-dependency-injection-in-aspnet-web-forms.html

Comment: Which web framework are you using? ASP.NET WebForms, ASP.NET MVC, ASP.NET WebApi, something else? Each framework requires different integration.

Comment: If you can go to Framework 4.7.2, why not go to 4.8? Or even better, just full .NET/Core?

Comment: @Steven to answer ur which web framework i am using, my answer is WebApiApplication

Comment: The minimum requirement for MS.DI is .NET 4.6.1, so from that point of view of either an MVC or Web API application, there is no reason to migrate to newer framework versions. This is different with Web Forms; Only Web Forms 4.7.2 and up support DI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## An ASP.NET Web API implementation

> ***WARNING:** This answer will **not** work when building an MVC web site. For MVC, please see my other answer.*

Assuming you are building an **ASP.NET Web API** application, you will have to implement a custom `System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.IHttpControllerActivator` and replace the default one inside your `Application_Start` event. Here's a complete working example that shows how to integrate Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection (MS.DI) into ASP.NET Web API 4.6.1 and up:

```cs
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Dispatcher;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        // Register all your controllers and other services here:
        services.AddTransient<Controllers.ValuesController>();

        var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider(new ServiceProviderOptions
        {
            // Prefer to keep validation on at all times
            ValidateOnBuild = true,
            ValidateScopes = true
        });

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(
            typeof(IHttpControllerActivator),
            new MsDiHttpControllerActivator(provider));
    }
}
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.Dispatcher;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public class MsDiHttpControllerActivator : IHttpControllerActivator
{
    private readonly ServiceProvider provider;

    public MsDiHttpControllerActivator(ServiceProvider provider)
    {
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    public IHttpController Create(
        HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor descriptor, Type type)
    {
        var scope = this.provider.CreateScope();
        request.RegisterForDispose(scope);
        return (IHttpController)scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService(type);
    }
}
```

Although it's also possible to implement a custom `IDependencyResolver` instead of an `IHttpControllerActivator`, using a controller activator is simpler because you have a clear place to start a new `IServiceScope`. Creating a service scope and resolving a controller from that scope is important, because resolving your controllers directly from the root `IServiceProvider` will lead to memory leaks and multi-threading issues.

Comment: Using MS.DI, can we add something like below? There's no Application_Start in our project. We have added this in a static class. 

`serviceCollection.AddEventLog(config => { config.LogName = "abc"; config.SourceName = "abc"; }));
var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
var loggerFactory = serviceProvider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();
var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("abc");`

The BuildServiceProvider breaks for the 1st time and then runs fine. Are we missing something?

Comment: Please post a new question here on Stack Overflow with all relevant details.

Answer (score 5):

## An ASP.NET MVC implementation

> ***WARNING:** This answer will **not** work when building a Web API web site. For Web API, please see my other answer.*

Assuming you are building an **ASP.NET MVC** application, you will have to implement a custom `System.Web.Mvc.IControllerFactory` and replace the default one inside your `Application_Start` event. Here's a complete working example that shows how to integrate Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection (MS.DI) into ASP.NET MVC 4.6.1 and up:

```cs
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        // Register all your controllers and other services here:
        services.AddTransient<HomeController>();

        var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider(new ServiceProviderOptions
        {
            // Prefer to keep validation on at all times
            ValidateOnBuild = true,
            ValidateScopes = true
        });

        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(
            new MsDiControllerFactory(provider));
    }
}
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public class MsDiControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private readonly ServiceProvider provider;

    public MsDiControllerFactory(ServiceProvider provider) => this.provider = provider;

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(
        RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        IServiceScope scope = this.provider.CreateScope();

        HttpContext.Current.Items[typeof(IServiceScope)] = scope;

        return (IController)scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService(controllerType);
    }

    public override void ReleaseController(IController controller)
    {
        base.ReleaseController(controller);

        var scope = HttpContext.Current.Items[typeof(IServiceScope)] as IServiceScope;

        scope?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Although it's also possible to implement a custom `IDependencyResolver` instead of an `IControllerFactory`, using a controller factory is simpler because you have a clear place to start a new `IServiceScope`. Creating a service scope and resolving a controller from that scope is important, because resolving your controllers directly from the root `IServiceProvider` will lead to memory leaks and multi-threading issues.

Comment: Hi steven and thanks for your answer, but my code is WebApiApplication and not MvcApplication. I have updated the question and I hope it helps. Sorry for any confusion

Comment: Hi @ZorevGnoz, see my second answer. This shows an example of Web API instead.

Comment: This works so well, be sure to identify which project type you need before you try to implement the solution for the other project type. <- Very embarrassed guy.